# sql selecting minimum date relative to another column's group

Tags: python, sql, postgresql

I have some data that looks like this, I am trying to find the minimum corresponding `next_start_date` with each unique `cancel_date`.

| group_id | individual_id | race | color_of_eye | cancel_date | next_start_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 001 | A | @@ | 2017-11-06 | 2018-04-16 |
| 2 | 002 | B | $$ | 2017-06-26 | 2017-06-26 |
| 2 | 002 | B | $$ | 2017-06-26 | 2018-01-23 |
| 2 | 002 | B | $$ | 2017-06-26 | 2019-02-16 |
| 3 | 002 | C | << | 2017-12-28 | 2018-01-23 |
| 3 | 002 | C | << | 2017-12-28 | 2019-02-16 |
| 4 | 003 | B | ** | 2010-01-26 | 2011-01-23 |
| 4 | 003 | B | ** | 2010-01-26 | 2019-02-16 |
| 5 | 004 | K | @@ | 2017-12-28 | 2018-01-23 |

Desired output:

| group_id | individual_id | race | color_of_eye | cancel_date | next_start_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 001 | A | @@ | 2017-11-06 | 2018-04-16 |
| 2 | 002 | B | $$ | 2017-06-26 | 2017-06-26 |
| 3 | 002 | C | << | 2017-12-28 | 2018-01-23 |
| 4 | 003 | B | ** | 2010-01-26 | 2011-01-23 |
| 5 | 004 | K | @@ | 2017-12-28 | 2018-01-23 |

I tried using a window function with

```
SELECT
      *,
      MIN(next_start_date) OVER (PARTITION BY individual_id, cancel_date) AS minimum_next_start_date
FROM table
ORDER BY
    individual_id, cancel_date, minimum_next_start_date
```

The results looks like this

| group_id | individual_id | race | color_of_eye | cancel_date | minimum_next_start_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 001 | A | @@ | 2017-11-06 | 2018-04-16 |
| 2 | 002 | B | $$ | 2017-06-26 | 2017-06-26 |
| 2 | 002 | B | $$ | 2017-06-26 | 2017-06-26 |
| 2 | 002 | B | $$ | 2017-06-26 | 2017-06-26 |
| 3 | 002 | C | << | 2017-12-28 | 2018-01-23 |
| 3 | 002 | C | << | 2017-12-28 | 2018-01-23 |
| 4 | 003 | B | ** | 2010-01-26 | 2011-01-23 |
| 4 | 003 | B | ** | 2010-01-26 | 2011-01-23 |
| 5 | 004 | K | @@ | 2017-12-28 | 2018-01-23 |

Should I do a `Min` for `minimum_next_start_date`, and `group by` every other column there is? Please help.

Comment: Please only tag a single RDBMS... not 3!

Comment: im putting the results of the query I run on the original table. there is only one original table

Comment: @queenofspades . . . I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: oh i see what you mean, i corrected it, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Why do you use a window function for a simple aggregate query?

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell, you want aggregation:

```
select group_id, individual_id, race, color_of_eye, cancel_date,
       min(next_start_date)
from t
group by group_id, individual_id, race, color_of_eye, cancel_date;
```

In Postgres, `distinct on` often has better performance.  If the `group by` defines the groups without the other columns, then you can use:

```
select distinct on (group_id, individual_id) t.*
from t
order by group_id, individual_id, next_start_date;
```

Comment: I have about 50 other columns, is listing everyone of them down under group by the only way?

Comment: @queenofspades . . . The second solution using `distinct on` is a better choice in Postgres.

Comment: ty Gordon, the individual can move to different groups each time it cancels and joins back, I put more emphasis on individual id. when I do the group by I will have to make it group ID as well, I worry it would mess the results. also, I run distinct on the table i have after using the window function eh?

Comment: @queenofspades . . . You can use both.